# SELECT Statement Across 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a web app I'm trying to profile and optimize and one of the last things is to fix up this slow running function.  I'm not an SQL expert by any means, but know that doing this in a one step SQL query would be far faster than doing it the way I'm doing now, with multiple queries, sorting, and iterating over loops.

The problem is basically this - I want the rows of data from the "users" table, represented by the UserData object, where there are no entries for that user in the "bids" table for a given round.  In other words, which bidders in my database haven't submitted a bid yet.

In SQL pseudo-code, this would be

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.role='BIDDER' AND 
users.user_id CANNOT BE FOUND IN bids.user_id WHERE ROUND=?
```

(Obviously that's not valid SQL, but I don't know SQL well enough to put it together properly).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a LEFT JOIN.
The LEFT JOIN creates a link between two tables, just like the INNER JOIN, but will also includes the records from the LEFT table ( users here ) that have no association with the right table.

Doing this, we can now add a where clause to specify we want only records with no association with the right table.

The right and left tables are determined by the order you write the join. The left table is the first part and the right table (bids here) is on the right part.

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN bids b
ON u.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE u.role='BIDDER' AND 
b.bid_id IS NULL
```

Comment: only thing left is to add ROUND = ? to the ON clause

Comment: Of course Fabian! this part of his question wasn't clear so I removed it for clarity sakes!

Comment: hehe, yes, the question is indeed not very clear ;) but to the original poster: please put it into the ON clause, it will not work in the WHERE clause-

Comment: As a style preference, I much prefer the "LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL" syntax over the sub-query syntax.  The code to me is a lot more clear and they will usually be optimized to the same execution plan (though sub-queries can be less performant in some cases, depending on which operator you use and the SQL engine).

Comment: I definitely agree on the performance point. I changed a Query that was executed on 10-12 millions records from 2-3 seconds to 0 second just by changing the sub queries to joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN bids b on b.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.role = 'BIDDER' 
AND b.user_id IS NULL
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a left join (as proposed by Dave) or using a sub-query:

```
select * 
from users u 
where u.role = 'BIDDER' and not exists (
    select *
    from bids b
    where b.user_id = u.user_id and b.round = ?)
```

Or equivalently

```
select * 
from users u 
where u.role = 'BIDDER' and u.user_id not in (
    select b.user_id
    from bids b 
    where b.round = ?)
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use the left join and you want to add the query parameter,  you have to put it in the ON clause (not the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN bids b
ON u.user_id = b.user_id AND b.round = ?
WHERE u.role='BIDDER' AND  b.bid_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from users
WHERE users.rol='BIDDER'
AND users.user_id not in (SELECT user_id FROM bids WHERE round =?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for performance comparison.  Given your pseudocode, you may find it more readable than the left join.

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE u.role='BIDDER'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM bids b
    WHERE b.round = ?
      AND b.user_id = u.user_id
  )
```